# Chrome - обновление расширения

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Начал писать расширение для `Chrome`... В середине задался вопросом "Как его потом обновлять?" искал информацию в сети, но нигде не упоминается про обновление или вообще не понятно...

Подскажите, как это реализовывается? Чтобы я загрузил плагин **на свой сервер**, и оттуда уже обновлял..

и еще: можно ли на все это посмотреть локально? то есть не загружая расширение в `Chrome Store`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate

`manifest.json` должен содержать `update_url`

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "update_url": "http://myhost.com/mytestextension/updates.xml",
  ...
}
```

По запросу возвращается xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'>
    <updatecheck codebase='http://myhost.com/mytestextension/mte_v2.crx' version='2.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

Соответственно `codebase` это путь к упакованному расширению, `version` - версия на основе которой и определяется необходимость обновления.
В xml может содержать информация о обновлениях нескольких расширений.

Для тестирования удобно запустить Chrome так:

```
chrome.exe --extensions-update-frequency=45
```

Так расширения будут обновляться раз в 45 секунд. По-умолчанию - несколько часов.

Больше информации в источнике.

Comment: А откуда брать ссылку, которую помещаем в "update_url"?